# Calculating previous Sunday Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Im trying to calculated the date for the previous sunday via the .setdate .getdate - 7 days method but it seem to work perfectly for calculating yesturday last week but not for sunday. Any ideas?

```js
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date();
var LWyesterday = new Date();
var LWSunday = new Date();

// Set yesturday date
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
console.log('yesterday = ' + yesterday);

// Calculated and set Sunday
var Sunday = new Date(today.getTime() - today.getDay() * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
console.log('recent sunday = ' + Sunday);

// Set yesturday last week
LWyesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 7);
console.log('last week yesterday = ' + LWyesterday);


// Set sunday last week
LWSunday.setDate(Sunday.getDate() - 7);
console.log('last week sunday = ' + LWSunday);
// returns Tue May 23 2017 14:08:24 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
// Should have been  Tue >**April**< 23 2017 14:08:24 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afmc9yon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed your real problem: 
Sunday might be in the last month.
Therefore the *Sunday.getDate()-7* is positive, not changing the LWSunday Month property...

So you also need to change the month ( in some cases) :

```
LWSunday.setDate(Sunday.getDate() - 7);
if(Sunday.getMonth()!==today.getMonth()){
   LWSunday.setMonth(LWSunday.getMonth()-1);
}
//same for year...
   console.log('last week sunday = ' + LWSunday);
```

OR you take the whole date:

```
var LWSunday = new Date(Sunday.getTime() - 7*24*3600*1000);
```

http://jsbin.com/yevutabuxe/edit?console

Comment: Far better to just get the previous Sunday by subtracting 7 days from the current Sunday. No need to adjust the month, that will happen anyway.

Comment: This code is not good: http://jsbin.com/hupufa/edit?js,console for 2017-01-02 (monday) it says that current sunday is 2017-01-01 which should be 2017-01-08, and the last sunday it says 2016-11-25 which should be 2017-01-01. Please see answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43821121/7765675

Comment: @RobG nope. its because he does a day=> day last week => offset from that to sunday ( 6.05 > 31.04 > 25.05 and not 25.04)

Comment: @ViktorCamp the sunday math is based on the users code, i think he wanted it like that...

Comment: @Jonasw—if *Sunday* is a Sunday then `Sunday.setDate(Sunday.getDate() - 7)` must be the previous Sunday. Subtracting 7 days using `7*24*3600*1000` is unreliable as not all days are 24 hours long (some are 23 and some are 25 over daylight saving boundaries).

Comment: @RobG if youre right, why does the users code dont work?

Comment: @Jonasw—you are correct regarding why the OP's code doesn't work, however there's a better way of calculating the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to set the month, since the `setDate` function takes care of automatically:

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp
>
> `Date.setDate(day)` - `day` an integer representing the day of a month.
>
> Expected values are 1-31, but other values are allowed:
>
> - 0 will result in the last day of the previous month
> - -1 will result in the day before the last day of the previous month
>
> If the month has 31 days:
>
> - 32 will result in the first day of the next month
>
> If the month has 30 days:
>
> - 32 will result in the second day of the next month

What you need is:

- > `getDay()` gives you back the day of the week (where Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, ... Saturday is 6)
  >
  > - you have to convert it to Monay is 1, ... Saturday is 6, Sunday is 7
  > - you can do the conversion by `today.getDay() || 7` (borrowing it from Damian)
  > - otherwise when today is Sunday the code will give you this Sunday as last week's Sunday
- > you have to decrease the day of the month (`getDate()`) by the day of the week (`getDay()||7`)

So in your case use: `LWSunday.setDate(today.getDate() - (today.getDay()||7));`

Similarly if you want to get current week's Sunday, then you have to add 7 days: `Sunday.setDate(today.getDate() - (today.getDay()||7) + 7);`

```js
var today = new Date();
var Sunday = new Date();
var LWSunday = new Date();

// Calculated and set Sunday
Sunday.setDate(today.getDate() - (today.getDay()||7) + 7);
console.log('recent sunday = ' + Sunday);

// Set sunday last week
LWSunday.setDate(today.getDate() - (today.getDay()||7));
console.log('last week sunday = ' + LWSunday);
```

You can also make a function out of it:

```js
if (!Date.prototype.getSunday)
  Date.prototype.getSunday = function() {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() - (dat.getDay()||7) + 7);
    return dat;
  }

if (!Date.prototype.getLastSunday)
  Date.prototype.getLastSunday = function() {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() - (dat.getDay()||7) );
    return dat;
  }

var date = new Date('2017-01-02');
console.log(date);
console.log('this Sunday',date.getSunday());
console.log('last sunday',date.getLastSunday());

var date = new Date('2017-01-01');
console.log(date);
console.log('this Sunday',date.getSunday());
console.log('last sunday',date.getLastSunday());

date = new Date('2017-05-02');
console.log(date);
console.log('this Sunday',date.getSunday());
console.log('last sunday',date.getLastSunday());

date = new Date('2017-05-07');
console.log(date);
console.log('this Sunday',date.getSunday());
console.log('last sunday',date.getLastSunday());
```

Comment: Its anti-pattern to code on browser prototypes because if the browser suddenly make overlapping naming your code might explode so it should be in separate class/function logic that you then call from your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var now = new Date();
var daysBack = -7 + (7 - now.getDay());

console.log(
    new Date(now.getTime()  + ((daysBack || -7)*1000*60*60*24))
)
```

We use `daysBack` variable so that we can get previous Sunday regardless what day of week is today. As `getDay()` returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday etc., we use a formula as the above. For example, if today is Saturday and `getDay()` gives us 6, we have here -7 + (7 - 6), then -7 + 1 and we get -6 what means closest Sunday was 6 days ago.

`daysBack || -7` is used to get previous Sunday in the case today is Sunday too.

Comment: This one gives previous Sunday regardless what day of week is today.

Comment: -7 + (7 - now.getDay()) = -1 * now.getDay(), and it doesn't work when today is Sunday

Answer (score 0):

`SetDate()` finds the day of month for the time value input.  But you're trying to find the whole date value by the looks.  If I understand what you're trying to do, what you really want is:

```
    LWSunday.setTime(Sunday.getTime() - 7*24*60*60*1000);
```